# Efficient chunk upload with Javascript / AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, azure, web-worker

I have functioning code which uploads files from the user to Azure BLOB storage of any size.  The issue is that if the files is larger than a certain size, I cut to chunked uploads (I also support continue-uploading).

While chunk uploading, the filereader is very slow.  I am unsure of how to fix this -- I assume with webworkers? Would that involve Parallel.js?

Another flaw is that I require being able to upload on IE9 eventually -- although it currently only works with HTML5 because I use Filereader. How am I supposed to do it without web workers without it being soul-crushingly slow? (I have 50 mbps upload and was getting 5 mbps).

EDIT: Thanks guys, that did it.  Instead of reading in file, I just:

```
var requestData = o['files'][0].slice(o.uploadedBytes, o.uploadedBytes + o.maxChunkSize);
o.data = requestData;
o.dataType = requestData.type;
o.type = "PUT";
o.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-blob-type', 'BlockBlob');    
};
```

And it works like a charm!

Comment: Why are you using FileReader?

Comment: Can you share some code? We're also using FileReader in our product and it seems to be working fine. We're not using any web-workers. We're splitting the file in 256 KB chunks. @RayNicholus - FileReader allows you to read part of a file so that you can upload really large files by splitting them in chunks and uploading those chunks.

Comment: @GauravMantri That is not what FileReader is used for at all.  Reading the file into memory simply to split it into parts is incredibly inefficient and unnecessary.  You should be using the `slice` method on the corresponding `Blob` instead.

Comment: @RayNicholus You mean something like this: `var fileContent = file.slice(startIndex, endIndex);                  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileContent);`? `file` is the blob object.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, that's correct.  `File` objects are on the `Blob` prototype chain, so they inherit everything from `Blob`.

Comment: @RayNicholus We actually make use of FileReader's `onloadend` event to trigger uploading the data: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/. Would appreciate if you find any issues with our approach.

Comment: @GauravMantri There is no need to use FileReader if you are simply going to to upload the blob/file.  Simply send it using XHR2 as the payload of the request (`xhr.send(blob)`) or using FormData (`var formData = new FormData(); formData.append("file", blob);) xhr.send(formData);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44428/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-ray-nicholus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern browsers you can `.slice` a file. This operation is very fast and solves your performance issue.

Older browsers don't support this. It's up to you to find a workaround that works, maybe a Flash uploader? Or simply limit the filesize in IE9.

Comment: Note that you can't enforce file size limits in IE9 or older due to lack of File API support.